# The multi-part identifier "Utility._userid" could not be bound

Tags: c#, sql

I have been getting this error while trying to make a delete statement in my C# WinForms app (database using SQL):

> The multi-part identifier "Utility._userid" could not be bound.

This is my code:

```cs
foreach (DataRow dr in dtbl.Rows)
{
    if (dr[1].ToString() == this.user_TXT.Text.ToString() && dr[2].ToString() == this.pass_TXT.Text.ToString())
    {
        Utility._userid = Int16.Parse(dr[0].ToString());//**this is where im getting the error**
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Select Remainder from OrderHeader where UserID=Utility._userid ",sqlcon);
        int oi = Convert.ToInt16(cmd1.ExecuteScalar());
        if (oi != 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("User cannot be deleted! Existant orders.");
        }
        else
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete * from Users where Username=this.user_TXT", sqlcon);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Dispose();
            MessageBox.Show("User has been deleted");
        }
    }
    else continue;
}
if (a == 0)
    MessageBox.Show("Wrong username or password!");
sqlcon.Close();
```

Comment: C# variables != SQL parameters. Use `command.Parameters.Add("@userId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(Utility._userid);` and reference `@userId` in the SQL

Comment: Thank you! But can you please elaborate what happened here?

Comment: Thought I was clear. You cannot use C# variables in SQL like that. You need to pass parameters as I described

Comment: Okay thank you and sorry I am new to this